# Saving large Python arrays to disk for re-use later --- hdf5? Some other method?

Tags: python, database, arrays, save, hdf5

I'm currently rewriting some python code to make it more efficient and I have a question about saving python arrays so that they can be re-used / manipulated later.

I have a large number of data, saved in CSV files. Each file contains time-stamped values of the data that I am interested in and I have reached the point where I have to deal with tens of millions of data points. The data has got so large now that the processing time is excessive and inefficient---the way the current code is written the entire data set has to be reprocessed every time some new data is added.

What I want to do is this:

1. Read in all of the existing data to python arrays
2. Save the variable arrays to some kind of database/file
3. Then, the next time more data is added I load my database, append the new data, and resave it. This way only a small number of data need to be processed at any one time.
4. I would like the saved data to be accessible to further python scripts but also to be fairly "human readable" so that it can be handled in programs like OriginPro or perhaps even Excel.

My question is: whats the best format to save the data in? HDF5 seems like it might have all the features I need---but would something like SQLite make more sense?

EDIT: My data is single dimensional. I essentially have 30 arrays which are (millions, 1) in size. If it wasn't for the fact that there are so many points then CSV would be an ideal format! I am unlikely to want to do lookups of single entries---more likely is that I might want to plot small subsets of data (eg the last 100 hours, or the last 1000 hours, etc).

Comment: Could you provide some more specific information on your problem? For instance, how many dimensions is the data in. Are you dealing with many arrays of a small number of elements each or a small number of arrays with a large number of elements? Do you think you'll be needing to run complex queries on this data? If your data is multi-dimensional and you could benefit from queries SQLite might make sense.

Comment: I have added some information as requested. Essentally I have a small number of one dimensional arrays, but each array has ~ millions of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDF5 is an excellent choice! It has a nice interface, is widely used (in the scientific community at least), many programs have support for it (matlab for example), there are libraries for C,C++,fortran,python,... It has a complete toolset to display the contents of a HDF5 file. If you later want to do complex MPI calculation on your data, HDF5 has support for concurrently read/writes. It's very well suited to handle very large datasets.

Comment: It seems like there are quite a few choices, but I will go with HDF5 for the reasons you specify :-)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use some kind of key-value database like Redis, Berkeley DB, MongoDB... But it would be nice some more info about the schema you would be using.

**EDITED**

If you choose [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) for example, you can index very long lists:

> The max length of a list is 232 - 1 elements (4294967295, more than 4
>   billion of elements per list). The main features of Redis Lists from
>   the point of view of time complexity are the support for constant time
>   insertion and deletion of elements near the head and tail, even with
>   many millions of inserted items. Accessing elements is very fast near
>   the extremes of the list but is slow if you try accessing the middle
>   of a very big list, as it is an O(N) operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single file with fixed record length for this usecase.  No specialised DB solution (seems overkill to me in that case), just plain old `struct` (see the documentation for struct.py) and read()/write() on a file.  If you have just millions of entries, everything should be working nicely in a single file of some dozens or hundreds of MB size (which is hardly too large for any file system).  You also have random access to subsets in case you will need that later.

Comment: Ah, I missed that 'readable' part :-}  Maybe you don't want to use struct.py then but plain old str()/int()/float().  And of course use a single file for each array (you wrote you have 30 of them).